# Issues with returning value out of Try function

Tags: python-2.7

I am attempting to return a integer value after testing the input for if it can be an integer to begin with. When giving a value that is not able to be converted (i.e. "One") then an actual integer it will instead return None.

I have been able to alter a global variable to be the integer to retrieve it and ran it before and after the print function. Both global variables worked correctly even if the try failed the first time but the print will always return None after a second try attempt

```py
def numTest():
  num = input("Give a number value:")
  try:
    int(num)
  except:
    print("That didn't work, how about a number this time?")
    numTest()
  else:
    return int(num)
print numTest()
```

I expect the print function to print the integer after the try either turns it into one or an input is given so that it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in a `try-else` block are only executed if there is no exception.

You probably want to put `return int(num)` at the same indentation level as `try`.

Better yet, you could put `return` both in front of the recursive call to `numTest`  and in front of the other use of `int(num)`, so it returns directly from both branches of the `try`/`except`.

Also, you should specify what kind of error you are expecting to catch. In this case, there really aren't many options, but it's a good habit to get into and it makes your code a little neater.

```
def numTest():
  try:
    return int(num)
  except ValueError:
    print("Try a number.")
    return numTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you missed a `return` inside the `except` clause, when you recursively called `numTest()`.

To understand why, try debugging it the following way:

1. Run the code and supply a no-integer value ("One", as in your own example);
2. An exception will be thrown in the `int(num)` and your call to `numTest()` **won't return anything** to it's caller (the main `print(numTest)`), since there is no `return` clause
3. Now supply a valid number ("1", for instance). This integer will be returned, but not forwarded, since there is no `return`.

The following version will make your code work:

```
def numTest():
    num = input("Give a number value:")
    try:
        int(num)
    except:
        print("That didn't work, how about a number this time?")
        return numTest()
    else:
        return int(num)

print(numTest())
```